Testing services with django-pytest: User.DoesNotExist
I'm trying to test functions with pytest. It returns No tables found. While i see migrate output and test sqlite3 database.
authentication/tests/test_services.py::test_register_user - users.models.User.DoesNotExist:
User matching query does not exist.
My conftest is:
import os

import pytest

from django.core.management import call_command
from rest_framework.test import APIClient

from users.models import User


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def delete_db():
    print("delete_db")
    try:
        os.remove("db_test.sqlite3")
    except Exception:
        pass


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def django_db_setup(delete_db, django_db_blocker):
    print("django_db_setup")
    with django_db_blocker.unblock():
        call_command('sqlflush')
    with django_db_blocker.unblock():
        call_command('migrate', '--noinput')
    yield


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='session')
# def user(data, django_db_blocker):
def user(django_db_setup, django_db_blocker):
    with django_db_blocker.unblock():
        user = User.objects.create(
            name='Test user',
            email='test@eaxmple.com',
            password='Password'
        )


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='session')
def guest_client():
    return APIClient()


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='session')
def user_client(guest_client, django_db_blocker):
    with django_db_blocker.unblock():
        client = APIClient()
        user = User.objects.get(email='test@example.com')
        response = guest_client.post('/api/v1/auth/login/', data={"email": user.email, "password": "Adminqwe1,"})
        token = str(response.json().get("access"))
        client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION="Bearer " + token)
        return client

Test user from fixture is created
my test file is:
import pytest

from authentication.services import register_user


@pytest.mark.django_db()
def test_register_user(guest_client):
    data = {'email': 'test1@example.com', 'name': 'Test user', 'password': 'Adminqwe1.'}
    user = register_user(data=data)
    assert user.name == 'Test user'
    assert user.check_password('Admninqwe1.') is True

tested function:
from users.models import User


def register_user(data):
    password = data.pop("password")
    user = User.objects.create(**data)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    return user

settings_test:
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db_test.sqlite3',
    }
}

pytest.ini:
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = config.settings_test

I have no ideas what's wrong.

You have to create fixture that create user in test_db.
@pytest.fixture
def test_user(django_db_setup, django_db_blocker):
    with django_db_blocker.unblock():
        user = User.objects.create(
            name='Test user',
            email='test@example.com',
            password='Password'
        )
        user.set_password('Password')
        user.save()
    return user

Now you have to call that fixture test_user in your test_register_user function like this.
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_register_user(guest_client, test_user):
    data = {'email': 'test@example.com', 'name': 'Test user', 'password': 'Adminqwe1.'}
    user = register_user(data=data)
    assert user.name == 'Test user'
    assert user.check_password('Adminqwe1.') is True

Please see this for more information https://djangostars.com/blog/django-pytest-testing/

Result is the same

The error was here email='test@eaxmple.com',

please see i just update my answer, in my fixture and my test function both email are different that's my mistake. now both are mistak.

Thank you for your attention. When something goes wrong it's time to take a break:) That really helped me
